# solving $\sin\left(x+\frac{3\pi }{5}\right)=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{5}-\frac{x}{2}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Trying to solve this:
$$\sin \left( x+\frac{3\pi}{\:5} \right) =2\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{5}-\frac{x}{2} \right) $$

I tried to divide $\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{5}-\frac{x}{2}\right)$ and expanded to get

$$\frac{\sin \left( x \right) \cos \left( \frac{3\pi}{5} \right) +\cos \left( x \right) \sin \left( \frac{3\pi \:}{5} \right)}{\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{5} \right) \cos \left( \frac{x}{2} \right) -\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{5} \right) \sin \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)}=2$$

I don't know how to proceed. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

I would start by noticing that

\begin{align*}
\sin\left(x + \frac{3\pi}{5}\right) = \sin\left(\pi - \frac{3\pi}{5} - x\right) = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{5} - x\right) = 2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{5} - \frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5} - \frac{x}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

Consequently, the proposed equation is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{5} - \frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5} - \frac{x}{2}\right) = 2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{5} - \frac{x}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$\sin\left(x + \frac{3\pi}{5}\right) = \sin\left(2(\frac x2 + \frac{3\pi}{10})\right) = 2\sin \left(\frac x2 + \frac{3\pi}{10}\right)\cos \left(\frac x2 + \frac{3\pi}{10}\right)$

Using $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} -y) = \cos y $ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} -y) = \sin y $ we can write,

$\sin\left(x + \frac{3\pi}{5}\right) = 2\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac x2 \right)\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac x2 \right)$.

So you're left with,

$2\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac x2 \right)\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac x2 \right) = 2\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac x2 \right)$

> $\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac x2 \right) = 0 $ or $\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac x2 \right)=1$

Could you solve now?

Comment: why $\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac x2 \right)=0$? If you divide each side by $2\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac x2 \right)$, they cancel leaving just $\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac x2 \right)=1$ as a solution, doesn't it?

Comment: You can't cancel like that. What if that term were zero ? For example, let's say $xy = x$. Then $x(y-1) = 0$. So if $x$ were $0$, $0\times(y-1) = 0$ for all $y$. Similarly if $y = 1 \Rightarrow (y-1) = 0$, $x\times0 = 0 $ for all $x$.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the clarification or explanation!

Comment: @Ak. About your deleted post: Check your browser to see if the problem persists after clearing your cookies and any ad-blockers. You can consider posting on Meta SE as well.

Comment: Yeah I'm about to post in Meta SE, tried in different browsers. The problem is still there